# Is $M_n(R)$ Dedekind if $R$ is Dedekind?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

> Definition: A ring is Dedekind if every nonzero proper ideal factors
> into a product of prime ideals.
>
> Let $R$ be a ring. $M_n(R)$ denotes the ring of matrices with elements
> from $R$. Is $M_n(R)$ Dedekind if $R$ is Dedekind?

I think the answer should be in some textbook, but I can't find it.

PS: I don't care the order of factors, so communitivity is not concerned.

Comment: Normally only commutative integral domains may considered to be Dedekind domains.

Comment: What is your definition of Dedekind ring? I guess you just mean the normal definition, but are you referring to the one Faith used (Dedekind prime ring)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just referring to Dedekind domains, then of course $M_n(R)$ is never a domain for$n>1$.  But the other important property (that $R$ is a hereditary ring) passes to $M_n(R)$.

Faith defined a Dedekind prime ring to be a hereditary, Noetherian, prime ring with no nontrivial idempotent ideals, and all those properties pass to the matrix ring, too. So the answer would be “yes” in that case.

Comment: Hhereditary ring sounds interesting. Would you introduce some classical textbooks or articles about Hhereditary ring?

Comment: @zongxiangyi *Lectures on modules and rings* by Lam, section 2E.  *Rings with chain conditions* by Chatters and Hajarnavis. *Noncommutative noetherian rings* by McConnell, Robson and Small. There are many more: you can just search for "hereditary ring" online.